# Vim: do unindentation manually

Tags: regex, vim, indentation

I would like to use substitution in Vim to do unindentation manually (instead of doing <)

So I do this:

```
:%s/^(^I)?//g
```

but it does not find the pattern. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you have 'magic' or 'nomagic' set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim does not understand the Perl-ish regexp syntax that you seem to use. It must be:

```
%s/^\t\?//
```

The `(...)` is not necessary, and must be written as `\(...\)`. Instead of `\t`, you could also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or use the general atom for whitespace `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `\(` and `\)` instead of `(` and `)`.  Also, make sure that the `^I` is a single character (e.g., created using control-v TAB) and not two (e.g., created using '^' and 'I').  Finally, I'm not sure if you even need/want the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question asked for a substitution, but I feel it necessary to propose some ex-commands that provide similar functionality:

- Reduce 1 level of indention for the entire file: `:%<`
- Reduce 1 level of indention for lines 1-5: `:1,5<`
- Reduce 1 level of indention for lines matching pattern: `:g/pattern/<`
- Remove all indention: `:%left` or `:%le` for short

For more help see:

```
:h :<
:h :g
:h :left
:h :range
```